# Disable or cache AngularJS OPTIONS requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request, ionic-framework

I'm using angular for my app and web development. I use `$http` for my data sending and receiving but I always have these OPTIONS requests before performing the real request.

I know the purpose of those requests but this will be a massive load for nothing and I have all the cross-origin headers provided on my server.

Is there any way to cache only OPTIONS requests or to disable those? I don't want to use `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This cache should be set via the server which would state how long the option is valid for by specifying an age (in seconds) in the header response. So the header would contain: AccessControlMaxAge: 3600

Answer (score 0):

you can use [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for disable requests

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('myInterceptor',
function ($q) {
    var interceptor = {
        'request': function (config) {

         if(config.method === 'OPTIONS') return;
        }
    };
    return interceptor;
});
```

and register it to the config

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
        '$injector',
        function ($injector) {
            return $injector.get('myInterceptor');
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
    at $http.serverRequest (http://192.168.178.20/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16965:25)

Comment: are you sure what this error depends on my suggested code ?

Comment: pretty sure. I just added you lines to my code. I can't post the whole code, but the lines where i pasted it. http://pastebin.com/Asrd98A1